# android Room livedata once

Tags: android, android-room

I'm using room in viewmodel to get list of Strings and show on RecyclerView. I use Livedata for returning list of room to observe it on Fragment and set data to RecyclerView

[image]

The problem is when I modify any data in my RecyclerView all the above steps runs again because I used LiveData and it listening for changes and recylerview rest. 
But why I used livedata? just to inform when Room process is done and get result

my question is should I use livedata for queries that no need to get updates?

if yes: how to prevent set data again?
if no: how to inform data is fetched while object without livedata cant be ovserved?

Comment: How did you solve it ?
I have the same issue